# Converting synchronous WCF service client calls to asynchronous

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I'm learning about Threading, Tasks and asynchronous coding and am trying to apply the concepts to Web Forms applications I work on daily.

So far I have:

- Configured Service reference like so:

[image: Configure Service Reference]

- Changed client calls from

  ```
  MyServiceClient msc = new MyServiceClient();
  try
  {
       myData =  msc.GetData();                    
       msc.Close();
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
       msc.Abort();
       throw;
  }
  ```

to

```
    MyServiceClient msc = new MyServiceClient();
    try
    {
         myData =  msc.GetDataAsync().Result;                    
         msc.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
         msc.Abort();
         throw;
    }
```

I am calling the result directly to implictly call .Wait() on the task and keep the code largely as is.

1. Is this correct in order to free up threads in the app pool for other work whilst doing I/O?
2. Do I need to handle exceptions differently?
3. Are Close() and Abort() still necessary and relevant?

Comment: `msc.GetDataAsync().Result;` is the same as `msc.GetData();`. What do you use Tasks if you won't use it as `await msc.GetDataAsync();`

Comment: @I4V `msc.GetDataAsync().Result;` is not same as `msc.GetData();`. Former involves two threads latter involves only one.

Comment: @I4V I'm not intending to process multiple service calls in parallel, my intention is to free up threads for other work. If I use `await` I then need to mark each method up the stack as `async` which is much more work. I may be trying to run before I can walk but this is my understanding currently.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Of course they are not the same, I just wanted to say the effect the caller thread will experience is the same. (BTW: *Former* doesn't need to involve two threads in theory)

Comment: @mizzle both ways block the calling thread. I still don't see an advantage in using `asynMethod.Result`

Comment: @I4V That is exactly my intention - to maintain the way the calling code works whilst also free up a load of paused I/O threads

Comment: @mizzle async/await is designed for this.

Comment: @I4V so your answer to Q1 is no? In that case the correct code is what I'm after.

Comment: @mizzle As i posted previously use `await msc.GetDataAsync();` or `msc.GetDataAsync().ContinueWith(.......)`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Not at all. `msc.GetDataAsync().Result` only uses one thread, and is practically identical to `msc.GetData()`.

Comment: @StephenCleary Typically when we use `msc.GetDataAsync().Result` calling thread will wait here, worker thread will finish the work and return the result right? So this involves two threads is what I mean. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: There is no worker thread in this case.

Comment: @StephenCleary Still unclear for me. Then how does `GetDataAsync` work without a worker thread?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: I have an [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) on my blog, and the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) are quite good as well.

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks, I'll take a look at it. are you talking about `await msc.GetDataAsync()`? not just only `msc.GetDataAsync().Result`? I was not talking about `async/await`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: There is no worker thread, whether you use `GetData` or `await GetDataAsync` or `GetDataAsync().Result`.

Comment: @StephenCleary I mean threadpool thread as worker thread. May be that is misleading? or your point is only one thread involved when using `GetDataAsync().Result`?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Please read the docs on how `async` works. `GetDataAsync` runs on the thread that called it (the UI thread), and it returns a task which represents the response from the server. *There is no thread* - be it worker, thread pool, OS, or driver - that is blocked waiting for the response from the server. *There is no thread* "executing" the returned task, because it's an event task, not a code task. When you call `Result`, you're blocking the UI thread, but there is no other thread involved at that time.

Answer (score 1):

> I am calling the result directly to implictly call .Wait() on the task and keep the code largely as is.

I don't recommend this at all. In the general case, [calling `Result` or `Wait` in `async` code can cause deadlocks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) (as I explain on my blog). It may work (currently) due to the way `svcutil` is implementing the methods, but I don't recommend getting into the practice of writing code like this.

It's much better to allow `async` to grow through the code base:

```
MyServiceClient msc = new MyServiceClient();
try
{
     myData = await msc.GetDataAsync();                    
     msc.Close();
}
catch (Exception)
{
     msc.Abort();
     throw;
}
```

> 1. Is this correct in order to free up threads in the app pool for other work whilst doing I/O?

No. There is really no point to what you're doing. You're not letting the calls be asynchronous at all.

If you use `await`, then yes, you do get the benefits of asynchronous operations (i.e., freeing up the UI thread).

> 1. Do I need to handle exceptions differently?

If you're using `await`, then no, your existing code would work fine. If you're using `Result`, then yes, all your exceptions will be wrapped in an `AggregateException`.

> 1. Are Close() and Abort() still necessary and relevant?

Yes.

Comment: Most comprehensive answer so far. If I require this data before rendering a page and therefore need to wait for this to complete it seems there is no benefit to using async calls. If I have multiple service methods to call before rendering a page is there any benefit to using `async` and `await` up the stack or does an array of Tasks and `WaitAll()` and using the synchronous methods do the same?

Comment: @mizzle: Actually, I recommend rethinking your page UI first. If the page is dependent on loading data, then have a "loading" state that will show immediately, and have the asynchronous data loading update that page to a "normal" state when the loading completes. This is more work but you get a fully responsive UI (e.g., even if the network is down your app won't freeze).

Answer (score 0):

If calling the async version and waiting for completion was better than the normal way, the framework could just do this transparently for you. The fact that it doesn't do that shows you that this approach is not good.

> If I use await I then need to mark each method up the stack as async which is much more work.

That's the deal. You have to **change the entire call stack** because your thread has to return control to the thread pool while the IO is running. You must exit *all* function on the stack. Thank god async/await makes this mostly a mechanical exercise.

For that reason you should use async/await *in response* to a performance need that you otherwise cannot get. Do not use it by default. First determine, whether you actually have too many threads at the moment or not. If not you very likely do not need async at all. Invest your time elsewhere.